# creating form and route - laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to learn laravel, so I create something like this:

Routes:

```
Route::get('foto/add', array('uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));
```

From:

```
{% extends layout_file %}

{% block content %}


    <div class="container" id="content" style="max-width: 600px">

    <div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4">

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i></span>
            {{ form_open({url: '/foto/add', class: 'form-horizontal'}) }}
            {{ form_text('name', '', {class: 'form-control'}) }}
        </div>
        <br>
        {{ form_submit('Create New Gallery', {name: 'submit', class: 'btn btn-lg btn-success btn-block'}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
    {{ form_close() }}
    </div> 
{% endblock %}
```

VideoController:

```
public function getCreate()
{

    return View::make('foto/addgallery');
}

public function postCreate()
{
    echo 'elo';

}
```

and when I click button, display error:

> Controller method not found.

I don't understand why..

Answer (score 0):

Your route says `HomeController@getIndex`, but you say that your controller is actually called `VideoController`, and the method you're trying to use in that controller is called `getCreate` rather than `getIndex`.

Try this instead:

```
Route::get('foto/add', array('uses' => 'VideoController@getCreate'));
```

... and if that doesn't work, there's something else wrong. :)

Comment: Well, from what you've given, it's impossible to know what the error might be if the above isn't the problem. Could you please post your HomeController file, and/or your complete routes file?

Comment: Shouldn't the route be post?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the common way to do it is since form is using post method by default:

routes:

```
Route::post('foto/add','VideoController@postCreate');
```

VideoController:

```
public function postCreate(Request $request){
     $photoName = $request->name;
     // ...
}
```